# Create maling list that skips rows with no data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that looks at a range of cells with email addresses and concatenates them into a comma delimited string.

```
Function CombineEmails(myRange As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In myRange
    CombineEmails = CombineEmails & "," & cell.Value
Next cell

CombineEmails = Right(CombineEmails, Len(CombineEmails) - 1)

End Function
```

I need to be able to add a range of empty cells to account for new email addresses in the spread sheet.   Also there are a few cells where the email address is null.

How do I ignore / skip null records in the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function CombineEmails(myRange As Range) As String 
    Dim cell As Range 
    For Each cell In myRange
        If Not Cell = vbNullString Then CombineEmails = CombineEmails & "," & cell.Value 
    Next cell

        CombineEmails = Right(CombineEmails, Len(CombineEmails) - 1)

        End Function
```

Just an If checking if the cell is null or not.

Comment: Thank you Damian. Works like a champ.   Appreciate the hand holding.

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to mark it as answer please ^^